# Функция, определяет факториал числа(Яндекс.Практикум)

Tags: c++, факториал

Задание: Написать программу, которая с определяет факториал числа(через функцию). Если число отрицательное, функция выводит 1.

Я написал это:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int arg;
int F = 1;
int Factorial(int x) {
    
    if(x<0)
        return 1;
    if(x>0)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<= x; i++)
            F = F*i;
        
    }
    return F;
}

int main() {
    cin>>arg;
    cout<<Factorial(arg)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении всё работает правильно, но при проверке Яндекс пишет мне:
Задача прошла 2/3 проверок

Возможные проблемы:

- Ваша функция неправильно вычисляет факториал положительнго числа

Я делаю что - то неправильно?

Comment: Какие ограничения на размеры чисел в задаче?

Comment: @dIm0n, аргумент функции находится в пределах от -10 до 10.

Comment: а что выведет функция если передать число 0 ?

Comment: @Leksor, этот случай в задании не рассмотрен. Написанная мной программа выводит 1.

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать сюда полное условие задания. Возможно, вы что-то упустили. Например, формат ввода или вывода не такой

Comment: Возможно, от вас хотят увидеть работу с рекурсией.

Comment: @dIm0n, Напишите функцию, которая
называется Factorial,
возвращает int,
принимает int и возвращает факториал своего аргумента.
Гарантируется, что аргумент функции находится в пределах от -10 до 10. Для отрицательных аргументов функция должна возвращать 1.

Comment: @e.n.shirokov, рекурсия в этом курсе пока что не рассматривалась, поэтому не думаю

Comment: @МСЧемодан не может быть такого, что функция проверяется не на 1 входе за раз, а на множестве входов? В таком случае надо `int F = 1;` внести под функцию. Сравните ваш вариант https://godbolt.org/z/57eKvP со внесённым под функцию

Comment: @dIm0n, помогло, благодарю

Comment: @МСЧемодан добавьте тогда **в ответ** исправленный код

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int arg;

int Factorial(int x) {
    int F = 1;
    if(x<=0)
        return 1;
    if(x>0)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<= x; i++)
            F = F*i;
        
    }
    return F;
}

int main() {
    cin>>arg;
    cout<<Factorial(arg)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```